# Index.html generation failed Angular 16

Tags: angular, migration, angular15, angular16, index.html

I have migrated Angular from 15 to 16 but when I try to build the project it throws an error:

[image: Index html failed]

**angular.json**:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "cc-front-end": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "hammerjs",
              "moment-timezone",
              "ng-click-outside",
              "snazzy-info-window",
              "rxjs",
              "jsona",
              "tsbase",
              "@agm/snazzy-info-window"
            ],
            "baseHref": "/themes/custom/cc_theme/cc-front-end/dist/",
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "aot": true,
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/images"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "./node_modules/tippy.js/dist/tippy.css",
              "./node_modules/tippy.js/animations/scale.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": false,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "cc-front-end:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "cc-front-end:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "cc-front-end:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/images"
            ],
            "include": [
              "**/*.spec.ts"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "cc-front-end-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "targets": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "cc-front-end:serve"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "cc",
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "cc"
    },
    "@angular-eslint/schematics:application": {
      "setParserOptionsProject": true
    },
    "@angular-eslint/schematics:library": {
      "setParserOptionsProject": true
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false,
    "cache": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to find the reason, why index.html is not generated?

**ng build output:**

[image: ng build]

Comment: ...It says flat out in the error message that it's because it's unhappy with your `target` in your `tsconfig.ts` file. Just change your `target` to `ES2022`, no?

Comment: @EliezerBerlin it's warning, nothing else. In Angular 15, it was working fine!

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue before, and it was because of a corporate proxy.

From what I gathered, it looks like Node is performing some background HTTP task (like downloading something), and when behind a corporate proxy, it can fail, and fail the index generation.

Try exiting your proxy or VPN, see if the issue persists.

If you need to keep using your proxy/VPN and build your app, you will need to add your Nexus/Artifactory/NPM repo in your project with a `.npmrc` file.

Comment: how to add project in `.npmrc` ?

Comment: it will be great if you can provide some steps!

Comment: You create a `.npmrc` at the root of your project. You have [all the documentation available](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/npmrc), and since it's very specific of your environment, I cannot really tell you how to write it. Best bet would be to ask your employer instead !

Answer (score 0):

try `ng s --prod` to  debug,

There must be some error while building

Comment: `Error: Unknown argument: prod`

Comment: did you try to install dependencies again ?

Comment: and run your project, there can be error in Html or CSS file

Comment: `ng build --configuration production` is successfully building!

Comment: Just found it on github, you can give it a try: `"optimization": { "scripts": true, "fonts": { "inline": true }, "styles": { "minify": true, "inlineCritical": false } },` [Index html generation failed on ng build in Angular 12](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20804)

Comment: Could you please post the hole ng build output, If there is an error or budget violations, the index.html file will not be generated.

Comment: yes, Please share the full output of ng build

Comment: Added the full output, please check.

Comment: Did you run the build command with the `--prod` flag? Please post you ng build command with the output!

Comment: @MeerArtefakt with `prod` flag the build is success.

Comment: @MeerArtefakt any other way to find out the error?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).